# Force perpendicular to velocity

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, vectors, velocity

In a recent physics class, I was told that force can change the direction of velocity as well as its magnitude simultaneously. My professor drew a diagram in which a particle is moving along a horizontal line and is acted upon by a force at angle $O$ with horizontal velocity. He said that component of force in downward direction will change the direction of horizontal velocity while the component of force along velocity will increase its speed which arose following doubts in my mind-

$1$  The perpendicular component of force will change the direction of velocity since instantaneous acceleration due to this component will be perpendicular to it, for an instant only. I want to understand what will be state of motion of this body after this instant.

$2$  if instantaneous acceleration is perpendicular to velocity then the direction of velocity changes in this instant. Now in projectile motion, instantaneous acceleration $g$ is perpendicular to the horizontal component of velocity, therefore by the above reasoning it should also change its direction.

All this has left me confused. Can anyone please help me to understand or tell me where I'm lagging?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at Newton's 2nd law, $$\sum F=ma. $$

In the perpendicular direction there is no speed. Meaning, when the object is moving horizontally it is not at the same time moving upwards. There is a horizontal speed component, $v_x$, but no upwards speed component, $v_y=0$, $$v=(v_x, 0). $$

If a force then pulls upwards, then apply Newton's 2nd law along this upwards direction. The upwards force will cause an upwards acceleration.

This upwards acceleration will in turn cause an upwards speed component, $v_y$. We now have $$v=(v_x, v_y), $$ which corresponds to a velocity that isn't horizontal anymore. The upwards force has caused the velocity to tilt upwards and have an angle.

Whenever a force is perpendicular, the above will happen. This also applies to gravity, which is why any object that you throw sideways, horizontally, gains a vertical speed component and begins falling down. We call this projectile motion. In special cases the force *turns as well* so that it always is perpendicular - after having tilted the velocity a bit, the force itself turns so it is perpendicular to this ned velocity. This is the case when you drive around a roundabout where you are constantly turning - and this is the case for a satellite in circular orbit where gravity always points down. Then we have perfect circular motion, meaning constant turning.

Comment: ok sir i understood what you want to convey but I have a query that when we thrown an object sideways initially gravity is perpendicular to velocity so at this instant is gravity only changing direction of velocity, what is actually happening during the initial instant

Comment: @lalittolani Yes, during the very first instant, the very first moment, gravity *only* causes turning. A perpendicular acceleration causes turning. A parallel acceleration causes speeding up/down (change in magnitude).

Comment: and my reasoning that perpendicular acceleration of gravity will only cause turning is that because the moment it will act can be considered to be equivalent to a small time interval dt in this dt time interval a small perpendicular component g*dt will be added to initial velocity vector which will tilt initial velocity vector towards itself a liitle without a significant change in magnitude

Comment: @lalittolani Correct.

Comment: ok sir thankyou so much helping me very grateful to you

Comment: if we launch projectile obliquely from ground then will acceleration due to gravity change direction of horizontal component of velocity since it is perpendicular to it?

Comment: above continued} or it will have no effect on a component of velocity

Comment: @lalittolani No force can influence a speed component that is perpendicular. So, no, gravity cannot ever influence the horizontal speed component. In fact, if you measure only the horizontal speed component of any thrown object, then you will find that it is constant. Only the vertical speed component changes due to gravity.

Comment: oh so you mean that   force perpendicular to velocity changes direction of velocity vector and if it is oblique to  velocity vector then it cannot change direction of component of velocity vector to which it is perpendicular

Comment: @lalittolani Not sure I follow. *Only* a perpendicular force can cause turning. *Only* a parallel force can cause speeding up/down. If a force is pulling at an angle (oblique, as you say) then it contains *both* a perpendicular and a parallel force component. So this force causes *both* turning and speeding up/down. If I have missed your point, then please let me know.

Comment: sir I'm entirely able to understand  what you want to convey. but the doubt arises in my mind is we say a force perpendicular to velocity at an instant changes direction of velocity at that instant so a force perpendicular to horizontal component of velocity will change direction of this horizontal component or not?

Comment: @lalittolani Yes, agreed. That is correct. A force pulling perpendicularly in a velocity vector or speed component will only turn that component.

Comment: Therefore we can say that gravity turns horizontal component of initial velocity in a ground to ground projectile motion

Comment: I am so sorry, @lalittolani, it might be the English wording, but I do not understand your sentence fully. If from what I understand, yes, gravity causes the path of the thrown object, which initially is horizontal, to bend downwards, yes.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to understand what will be state of motion of this body after [the first] instant.

That depends on the nature of the force. if the force is acting in a constant direction (e.g. gravity) then after the first instant there is a component of the force parallel to the velocity of the object (because the direction of the object's velocity has changed). This component will accelerate the object. On the other hand, if the force is *always* perpendicular to the object's velocity (e.g. an object on the end of a string) then it will continue to change the direction of the object's velocity, but not its magnitude.

> In projectile motion, instantaneous acceleration g is perpendicular to horizontal component of velocity, therefore by above reasoning it should also change it's direction.

Yes, and it does. The direction of an object moving under gravity (projectile motion) is, in general constantly changing, as the object moves in a parabola. There is just one exception to this - if the object is initially moving straight up (or down) then its direction of motion does *not* change because there is no component of gravity perpendicular to its velocity.

Comment: yes sir i know that direction of projectile continuously changes but i want to ask that a force perpendicular to velocity changes it's direction and therefore the gravitational force perpendicular to horizontal component of velocity should change it,s direction but it doesn,t actually changes